# OpenSSL: SSL_write abnormal latency

Tags: performance, sockets, openssl

I use `OpenSSL` along with a TCP socket. Non-blocking (`O_NONBLOCK`) mode is set by `fcntl` and Nagle's algorithm is disabled by `TCP_NODELAY`.

I experience a huge (`~45ms`) latency between `SSL_write` method returns and data actually captured by `tcpdump`. The length of my message is `~1100` bytes.

My understanding is that if the underlying `BIO` is a socket, then no-buffering should be involved. Am I wrong? What may cause such a poor performance of a method?

Comment: The ways you try to reduce latency are sound, even though O_NONBLOCK should have no effect at all. But of course there might be a difference between what you describe and your actual implementation. I recommended to show a *minimal but working* example what you do so that one can reproduce your problems and help you to fix these.

Comment: Thank you Steffen. You are right, I should have done it in the very beginning. I just finished a very simply example but couldn't reproduce it so far. The difference between that example and my real application is that I am keeping two SSL connections to the same server and port. May it somehow affect one of the links? I'm now trying to provide a working example which reflects my application in a better way.

Comment: I call `SSL_CTX_new`, `SSL_new`, `SSL_set_fd` and `SSL_connect` twice (one for each client connection) but in `tcpdump` output I can only find a single `Client Hello` message. I am a bit confused.

Comment: The few selected information you provide so far don't help much when taken out of the context of your unknown code. Please provide a minimal and working example to reproduce your problem.

Comment: ~45 ms does not seem that bad. It sounds pretty good to me. Also see [Optimizing NGINX TLS Time To First Byte (TTTFB)](https://www.igvita.com/2013/12/16/optimizing-nginx-tls-time-to-first-byte/). It discusses how to make Nginx faster by tuning OpenSSL. It may apply to your use case as well.